# Regular tetrahedron

Tags: geometry

Calculate the distance between the slanted wall heights of the regular tetrahedron with edge lengths $a$.

I have problem with visualization where the distance is.

Let's say we have such situation($MC$ is height) and draw yet height $DP(BC)$, so the quested length is between $P$ and projected point $P$ on $MC$ ?

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: No, the length would be between the closest pair of points, one on $MC$ and one on $DP$.

Comment: can you give me hint how to determine these point?

Comment: Mm... Jessica, unfortunately, I don't know what kind of tools you are expected to use in the homework. If it were up to me, I would solve the problem using linear algebra. Most likely I wouldn't even find these two points explicitly, but rather find the required distance using an "indirect" method. Could you tell us what kind of course this is? Otherwise, it may be hard to give an answer at the appropriate level.

Comment: I don't have imposed method to solve this problem but I'd prefer the high school level solution. Could you explain how looks the "indirect" method?

Comment: I'm making calculations to give you an answer, but while I'm doing it, here is a note: I think the answer depends on which pair of heights you choose. The pair $(CM, DP)$ that we're talking about is one thing. But you could also consider point $Q$ which is the middle of $CD$ and look at the pair of heights $(CM, BQ)$. These two are situated differently than the two before, and the answer may be different. So it would be good to know which distance you need.

Comment: maybe first the pair $(CM,DP)$ and later we see what happen for $(CM,BQ)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M$ be the middle point of $AB$ (as in the picture), and $P$ be the middle point of $BC$. We shall find the distance between segments $CM$ and $DP$.

First, it is clear that the answer is proportional to $a$, so I will just assume that $a=1$ to make formulas shorter.

The plan is very simple. I will calculate lots of vectors, and for my calculations I will use vectors $\overline{BA}, \overline{BC}, \overline{BD}$ as a basis. In the calculations to come I will use dot products of these vectors, which I denote by $(,)$. Their lengths are all equal to $1$, so their products by themselves are $1$:
$$
(\overline{BA}, \overline{BA}) = 
(\overline{BC}, \overline{BC}) = 
(\overline{BD}, \overline{BD}) = 1.
$$

The pairwise dot products are equal to $1/2$, because the angle between each two of these vectors is 60 degrees, and its cosine is $1/2$. So we have
$$
(\overline{BA}, \overline{BC}) =
(\overline{BC}, \overline{BD}) = 
(\overline{BD}, \overline{BA}) = 1/2.
$$

Now, let $Q$ be a point on *line* $MC$ and $R$ be a point on *line* $PD$ such that the distance between $Q$ and $R$ is the smallest possible. We will see later that in fact $Q$ is on *segment* $MC$ and $R$ is on *segment* $PD$, so the length of $QR$ is the answer to our problem.

To find where $Q$ and $R$ are situated, let's use the parametric line equations in vector form:
$$
\begin{align}
\overline{BQ} &= \overline{BC} + \alpha\left(\overline{BC} - \frac{1}{2} \overline{BA}\right) \\
\overline{BR} &= \overline{BD} + \beta\left(\overline{BD} - \frac{1}{2} \overline{BC}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Here $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are some constants that we have to find. First, let's subtract these equations to get vector $\overline{QR}$:
$$
\overline{QR} = \overline{BR} - \overline{BQ} =
\frac{1}{2}\alpha\overline{BA} + \left(-1 - \alpha - \frac{1}{2}\beta\right)\overline{BC} + (1 + \beta)\overline{BD}.
$$

It should be clear that vector $\overline{QR}$ must be orthogonal to both lines $MC$ and $PD$. In terms of dot products this can be written as a system of two equations:
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\overline{QR}, \overline{BC} - \frac{1}{2}\overline{BA}\right) &= 0; \\
\left(\overline{QR}, \overline{BD} - \frac{1}{2}\overline{BC}\right) &= 0.
\end{align}
$$
Now, using our formula for $QR$ and the known dot products of our basis vectors, we can boil these equations down to the following:
$$
\begin{align}
6\alpha + \beta &= -4; \\
\alpha + 6\beta &= -6.
\end{align}
$$
Solving the system, we get $\alpha = -\frac{18}{35}$ and $\beta = -\frac{32}{35}$. The fact that both numbers are between $-1$ and $0$ shows that both points $Q$ and $R$ lie on their respective heights, not on their continuations.

And now the deed is almost done. We know $\alpha$ and $\beta$, so we can find
$$
\overline{QR} = -\frac{9}{35}\overline{BA} -\frac{1}{35}\overline{BC} + \frac{3}{35}\overline{BD}.
$$
To find its length, we find its dot product with itself (using the known dot products of the basis vectors). The result of this calculation is that $(\overline{QR}, \overline{QR}) = \frac{70}{35^2}$, therefore $|QR| = \frac{\sqrt{70}}{35}$. And that is our answer.

If we come back to an arbitrary value of $a$ instead of $1$, it is clear that the answer will be $\frac{\sqrt{70}}{35}a$.

I am really, really not in the mood to do the same amount of calculations for pair $(CM, BQ)$. Also, there surely is a shorter way to do this. Maybe calculations will be easier if you choose your basis better. I picked one at random and stuck with it. There should also be a solution without linear algebra, but somehow I don't feel like looking for it now. Maybe someone will provide one in another answer.

*UPDATE:* note that this method may look like an overkill, but there is an upside. It gives you some extra information as a bonus. We know not only the distance between heights, but the actual two points where they come closest to each other. The $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that we found tell us that point $Q$ divides $CM$ with ratio $18:17$ (almost in the middle), and point $R$ divides $DP$ with ratio $32:3$ (very close to point $P$).

Comment: You're welcome. I decided not to go with the "indirect" approach. With that approach you just find the vector product $[CM, DP]$, and then the resulting distance is $|([CM, DP], CD)| / |[CM, DP]|$ (I'm omitting vector bars). The drawback is this finds the distance between *lines*, not segments. The answers happen to be the same in our case because the points in the closest pair lie on the segments, not outside of them.

Comment: @Jessica If you have problems in any step, feel free to ask. I can always fill in the details.

Comment: well I need to admit that your solution is too hard for me, becouse I haven't learnt parametric line equation yet, but do you think it is possible to solve this problem using more elementary method for example by similar triangles  ?

Comment: @Jessica I'm certain that it's possible, I just took the easy way out by using algebra and avoiding the need to really think. On another note, parametric line equations are very easy. In this case they just say $\overline{CQ}=\alpha\overline{MC}$ and $\overline{DR}=\beta\overline{PD}$. It just says that $CQ$ is parallel to $CM$ (herce $Q$ is on line $CM$), and $DR$ is parallel to $DP$ (hence $R$ is on line $DP$).

Comment: I would like to calculate the second distance (with the same method as you) $(CM,BP)$ where $P$ is middle of $DC$, but I encounter a problem when I need to determine my basis. Let $QR$ be searched distance where Q lie at $MC$ and $R$ at $BP$. Then I have $\vec{QR}=\vec{AR}-\vec{AQ}$ and here I have problem with which vectors take for basis, could you help me? You don't need to calculate it, just help me to pick the proper vectors. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Jessica It's not really that important which basis you choose. It should work out fine if you use vectors $\overline{AB}, \overline{AC}, \overline{AD}$.

Comment: ok if I choose those basis then I have $\displaystyle \vec{AQ}=\vec{AC}+\alpha(\vec{AC}-\frac{1}{2}\vec{AB})$ and I don't know how to determine $\vec{AR}$ in terms of $\vec{AB}$, $\vec{AC}$, $\vec{AD}$. Could you help me with it?

Comment: Sure. $P$ is the middle of $DC$, therefore $\overline{AP} = \frac{1}{2}(\overline{AC} + \overline{AD})$, and therefore $\overline{BP} = \overline{AP} - \overline{AB} = -\overline{AB} + \frac{1}{2}(\overline{AC} + \overline{AD})$. Then $\overline{AR} = \overline{AB} + \overline{BR} = \overline{AB} + \beta \overline{BP} = \overline{AB} + \beta(-\overline{AB} + \frac{1}{2}(\overline{AC} + \overline{AD}))$. Maybe you'll want to flip the sign of $\beta$ to make it more like the other equation, it's a matter of taste.

Comment: By the way, if we talk about little details, maybe it would be better to flip the sign of $\alpha$, not $\beta$. That is more natural. My choice of signs in the answer above wasn't the best. It doesn't affect the final answer, but it looks kinda bad.

Comment: @Jessica it looks correct. The difference of signs is because of what I said. If you'd started with $\overline{AR} = \overline{AB} -\beta\overline{BP}$, then the resulting $\beta$ would be $-\frac{3}{5}$. Since you started with $\overline{AR} = \overline{AB} + \beta\overline{BP}$, you got $+\frac{3}{5}$. If you'd used the equation $\overline{AR} = \overline{AB} + 100\beta\overline{BP}$, then you would've got $\beta = \frac{3}{500}$. The crux of it is: the $\beta$ you get depends on how you write the equation for point $R$. But the actual point $R$ you get is always the same.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to answer your question (with my own interpretation). Several lines have been added to your picture. See below.[image]

First of all, because MC is on the base (according to your picture), it should not be used as 'slant height'. To certain extend, you are allowed to do so because the figure is regular.

I found two of the slant heights, one is DM on face DAB and the other is DP on face DBC. The 'P' that you are using is not very clear because it was not shown in your picture.

To find the required distance is **impossible** because there are too many answers (ranging from 0 to MP). I guess what you are looking for is the MAXIMUM distance between these two slant heights. If this is true, then the answer is MP, which is eventually equal to 0.5a  because triangle BMP (was mistakenly written as DMP) is equilateral.

Comment: your heights are not oblique, because they are included in one plane

Comment: There are only 3 lines can be classified as 'slant heights' including the 2 that I have mentioned plus the one on the face DAC (which is the same as face DBC, geometrically speaking). Any two of them will definitely lie on a plane. There is no such thing as the two slant heights are oblique to each other. One altitude on one plane may be oblique to another altitude of another plane. In that case, one of these altitudes cannot be qualified as 'slant height'.

Comment: Triangle $DMP$ is not equilateral!

Comment: Should be triangle BMP. My mistake. Thanks for pointing that out.